# Change parent panel of GUIDE object

Tags: matlab, parent-child, matlab-guide

I have a Matlab GUIDE figure with nested panels. I also have control objects on top of the panels. Here's a notional example:

[image: guide panels]

In order to align all of the checkboxes, they all need to be in the same control group. I want to move the checkboxes so that their parent is the main panel rather than one of the sub-panels. The sub-panels are just there for visual grouping and don't really have a functional value.

The object browser shows the relationships, but I see no way to change it. I've tried pasting the objects I want to move outside the sub-panel and dragging them back in, but they automatically get added to the sub-panel. If I paste outside of the sub-panel I can use the arrow keys to move them back in and the parent will stay the main panel, but that gets to be tedious.

How can I change the parent panel of a GUIDE control object?

Comment: @Suever, not sure if you saw my response before your answer was deleted. I want to be able to align components from multiple sub-panels, so they need to all be in the same control group.

Answer (score 1):

Building the GUI with `guide` a possible solution could be:

- add the main `uipanel`
- add all the `checkbox` in the main `uipanel'
- align them (e. g. by selecting some of them and then use the `Align Objects` tool on the guide toolbar
- add the secondary `uipanel` over some of the `checkbox`. It will cover the `checkbox'
- select the secondary `uipanel`
- right-click on the mouse to pop-up the context menu
- select the `Send to Back` option

[image]

If you want to create the GUI "programmatically" you can:

- create a `figure`
- add the main panel with [uipanel](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html)
- add the checkboxes with [uicontrol](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) setting the `Style` property to `checkbox` and the `position` property so that they will be placed in the main panel
- add the secondary uipanel. Also in this case the secondary `uipanel` will mask the `checkbox`
- push the secondary panel back using the [uistack](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html) function

Thsi is a possible implementation

```
% Create the figure
figure
% Add the Main uipanel
p1=uipanel('units','normalized','position',[.1 .1 .5 .7],'title','Main Panel')
% Add come checkboxes
cb1=uicontrol('parent',p1,'style','checkbox','units','normalized', ...
   'position',[.1 .7 .3 .1],'string','checkbox 1')
cb2=uicontrol('parent',p1,'style','checkbox','units','normalized', ...
   'position',[.1 .6 .3 .1],'string','checkbox 2')
cb3=uicontrol('parent',p1,'style','checkbox','units','normalized', ...
   'position',[.1 .5 .3 .1],'string','checkbox 3')
% Add the Secondary uipanel
p2=uipanel('parent',p1,'units','normalized','position',[.05 .4 .4 .5], ...
   'title','Secondary Panel')
% Push the secondary uipanel back
uistack(p2,'bottom')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: This is nice, assuming I've planned everything out ahead of time. The issue arises when I'm building on what I've already created. I would rather not have to delete the secondary panel, add the new buttons, then re-add the panel.